# appending text into textBox not adding all fields from recordset

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a form **myForm** with a text box **myText**.

In the **onLoad** function, I have written code that is supposed to append all the rows from a recordset, **a database's lockfile**, into the **myText** text box.

What actually happens is, only the first field of four fields is appended into the textbox.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cn2 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i, j As Long

cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cn.Open "Data Source=Z:\myDatabase.mdb"    
cn2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
    & "Data Source=Z:\myDatabase.mdb"

Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

    Me.myText.SetFocus
    Me.myText.text = ""
    Do While Not rs.EOF            
        Me.myText.text = Me.myText.text & rs.Fields(0) & vbTab & rs.Fields(1) & vbTab & _
        rs.Fields(2) & vbTab & rs.Fields(3) & vbCrLf
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

I tried

```
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0) & vbTab & rs.Fields(1) & vbTab & rs.Fields(2) & vbTab & rs.Fields(3)
```

and all four fields showed in the immediate window.

**EDIT:**
I took out the vbtab, since it's not supported and the file itself already has spaces, and I changed `Me.myText.text` in

```
Me.myText.text = Me.myText.text & rs.Fields(0) & rs.Fields(1) & _
        rs.Fields(2) & rs.Fields(3) & vbCrLf
```

to `Me.myText`.
Now my code seems to work in the beginning. When I debug step by step the text box fills like it's supposed to, but when Code exits the do while loop, only the first field of the first row shows in the text box.

`debug.print Me.myText` before exiting the loop shows all the rows. After exiting the loop still shows all the rows. But in the form, the textbox is only showing the first record, first field.

The form and the textbox both do not have any events other than this event, which is on the forms load.

What is wrong?

Comment: In the design view of the form, are scroll bars and multiple lines allowed on the text box?

Answer (score 1):

Use the property .Value (which is the default property for textbox) , not .Text

so Me.myText.Text  ==> Me.myText.Value or Me.myText

The textbox support multi line with vbCrLf.

tab with vbTab  is not supported

define myvbTab= "    " as a tab separator instead of vbTab

Modify the following fragment of your code:

```
 myvbTab= "    "
dim row_data
 Do While Not rs.EOF    
    row_data = rs.Fields(0) & myvbTab& rs.Fields(1) & _  
    myvbTab & rs.Fields(2) & myvbTab& rs.Fields(3) & vbCrLf        
    Me.myText= Me.myText & row_data
   ' be sure that data is displayed, to know if control characters in row_data
    Debug.Print  row_data
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

**Edit:**

To isolate the problem can you run that code:(independent of reading recordset)

```
 Me.myText.Value = "start  "
 Dim tabChar As String

tabChar = Chr(9) '"   " 
Me.myText = Me.myText & "one" & tabChar & "two" & vbCrLf
Me.myText = Me.myText & "three" & tabChar & "four" & vbCrLf
```

it should display

```
start    one   two
three  four
```

Comment: Thanks for the `vbTab` tip.

Comment: I used your code, and at first it seems to work. When I debug the text box fills as it is supposed to,  but when I step through `end sub` all the lines in the textbox disappear except the first field of the first row of the recordset. If I stop the code running before I get to `end sub`, the lines stay in the text box.

Comment: comment line set focus, and use the Me.myText , add debug.Print to show what comming , may be there are control characters reterived from recordset

Comment: @M. Hassan, I checked. There isn't anything. The text all stays in until end Sub.

Comment: it should what you see in debug (immediate window) is as in text box. can you confirm that debug show valid data

Comment: check properties of textbox: mask  none, text format none , scrollbar vertical, text allign : left. Be sure that no other event handling code applied on the textbox that may clip text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118835/discussion-between-m-hassan-and-mjh).